# Deploy Ajax cross-domain to Microsoft-based server

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess

Was wondering if anyone is familiar the ajax-cross-domain function from this site: http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com

Im trying to duplicate and deploy on a Microsoft-based web server, but not getting any successful results.  Original example was deployed on a Unix/Apache web server.

Although the site indicated that this may be deployed on a Microsoft-based server, I am getting a blank page when testing with the simple ACD.responseText, and the following Console error log:

- [Error] SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#' (ACD.js, line 1)
- [Error]    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ACD global code
  (test.htm, line    7)

These are the steps I have taken so far with our MS server:

1. Allowed all Unknown CGI scripts in Web Service Extensions of IIS6
2. Created a cgi-bin folder and allowed all permissions to IWAM and IUSR
3. Copied source code, placed and named inside folder cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js
4. Created .htaccess with Notepad and saved to cgi-bin/ACD/.htaccess
5. Downloaded and installed ActivePerl and was able to test that it is
   functional
6. Created the test.htm without any modifications to the
    @_allowed_uris

Any help in getting this deployed to a Microsoft-based server is greatly appreciated.

Octavious

my test.htm file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ACD test page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?uri=(http://www.google.com)"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   alert(ACD.responseText);
  </script> 
 </head>
<body>&nbsp;</body>
</html>
```

ACD.js: [Source Code](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/ACD-source.txt)

Comment: your "acd.js" is actually perl, not javascript. Close, but no cigar... Just setup CORS, you don't need to paint yourself into some weird corner on the server to do cross-domain ajax these days...

Comment: @dandavis
Figured that .js file was perl, that's why ActivePerl was installed.  In any case, I opted to simply configure an Apache web server and was able to successfully run the script.  Have no clue what CORS is.  My goal is to scrape raw html tag of a specific  (external) website.  Looking over AJAX/JSONP (although have very little knowledge of it) does not seem to be the correct process for me.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: YQL might make scraping easier if that's what you're trying to do. it will turn html into jsonp for you.